# Angular Material input elements height issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have been working with anguarljs + angular material, where I am using all inputs provided by angular material but the problem is that if I have 10 or 15 controls on my form then it takes lots of space on the screen due to each input height. Is there a way that we can use the same controllers with less height.
Thanks.

Comment: Share the screenshots and code.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the size of

```
md-input-container {
 heigth : 10px;
}
```

Comment: Let me check, then I will come back. Thanks